# How to always return focus to a specific item in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using Qt 6.2 and QML, Qt Quick 2.
There are general keyboard event handling(used throughout the application) in my root window item, and I want to make the window is always focused(even after interacting other qt quick items).

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: root
  Item { 
    id: generalKeyEvents
    Keys.onPressed: (event)=> {
      if (event.key == Qt.Key_Escape) Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
    }
  }
  SpinBox {
    /*
      After interacting this item, I want focus back to @root. 
    */
    value: 10
    onValueModified: {
      console.log(value)
      root.focus = true // This might works, but I have bunch types of items; any efficient way?
    }
  }
}
```

There is no need to interact other items in keyboard. Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

One approach for your key handling is to stack all items below your key handler item. In this case, the key events bubble up the item hierarchy.

```
Item {
    id: generalKeyEvents

    // fill the hole screen
    anchors.fill: parent        
    
    // grap focus at first to receive key events right from the start
    focus: true

    Keys.onPressed: (event) => {
                        console.log("key pressed");
                        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Escape) Qt.callLater(Qt.quit)
                    }
    
    // stack items below general key handler item
    SpinBox {
        /*
            After interacting this item, I want focus back to @root.
        */
        value: 10
        onValueModified: {
            console.log(value)
            // root.focus = true // This might works, but I have bunch types of items; any efficient way?
        }
    }
}
```

This is not solving the focus a specific item problem. But I think, this answere is solving your base problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is quite aggressive since every time your item loses focus, it schedules to have the focus to return back as soon as possible via `Qt.callLater`:

```
    Item {
        id: generalKeyEvents
        focus: true
        onFocusChanged: if (!focus) Qt.callLater(forceActiveFocus)
    }
```